# Download files and save them locally in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, io, synchronization

I'm beginning a project where I need to write a Chrome extension which will have to be able to run offline and synchronize once online again. So I would like to know if there is any mean for a Chrome extension to download files and save the locally without prompting the user for each file (the amount of files could be considerable)

I have seen the chrome.storage module, which is able to do something similar, but I'm worried about performance, if there are many files. So if you have some information about performance, I'm interested, too.

**Edit:** I tested with Chrome's Filesystem features, and here is my source:

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

function onError(e) {
  console.log('Error', e);
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/2/26/10_francs_Mathieu_1987_F365-28_revers.jpg', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {

window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, 1024 * 1024, function(fs) {alert(fs.root.name);}, onError);

  window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, 1024 * 1024, function(fs) {
    fs.root.getFile('image.jpg', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
      fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {

        writer.onwrite = function(e) {};
        writer.onerror = function(e) {};

        var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: 'image/jpeg'});

        writer.write(blob);

      }, onError);
    }, onError);
  }, onError);
};

xhr.send();
```

It seems to work, but I can't see my file anywhere. I tried some other thing for the save path, like giving an absolute path, without success. Any idea?

Comment: Do you need to save the files on the user's file system, or does a virtual filesystem also do the job?

Comment: I don't see what you mean by virtual filesystem, in the context.

Comment: A sandboxed filsystem, see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: I'm looking at this just now, and it may do. I'm writing a short poc...

Comment: It *seems* to work (no error in the Javascript console), but I can't see my file anywhere.

Comment: That's what sandboxed/virtual mean. The files are available in a virtual sense -- the HTML5 APIs act as if there were real files -- but they don't exist anywhere on the local filesystem. They do exist in a literal sense, of course, but they are obfuscated so that it's not possible for your local filesystem to see them. This makes it impractical for local malware to infect the sandboxed filesystem, and vice-versa.